# Admob not showing banner ads on android pie

Tags: android, firebase, admob

The interstitial ads working in all devices, but the banner not showing in android pie on devices like Samsung S8, The banner working fine on other devices with lower api, admob activated two years ago it is working fine i noticed this problem by accident.

All my app have same problem, Banner working on lower "android Pie" perfectly

I am using latest api

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
```

Also added meta-data in manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <activity
```

THIS IS MY CODE

```
 MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX");
    AdView mAdView =  findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Layout code

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
```

Also there is no margin or padding in layout That holding Adview, banner working on Samsung s4 Huaweie etc using same code above

*** Update

I have another app didnt update long time ago using

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

and api

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
```

and

```
    compileSdkVersion 27
```

Admob banner working fine on Samsung s8 , any suggestions ? i think this is common problem...

Comment: same problem encountered, any news?

Comment: No news same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dreamer

I'm able to get admob banners in Android 9 phones after adding the following line inside android/app/build.gradle, dependecies:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
```

pls. check if this can also fix your problem.

Update: another place I forgot to mention, i.e. the android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <application
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="NameOfYourApp"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <uses-library android:name=org.apache.http.legacy android:required=false/>
```

i.e. add 2 lines:

(1) Inside `<application>`

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

(2) Right after `<application>`, but before `</application>`

```
 <uses-library android:name=org.apache.http.legacy android:required=false/>
```

Comment: @dreamer, Pls. check the updated answer, it is because some ads are still using http but the Android 9 by default can only use https.

Comment: my compile and target sdkversion is 28, how about yours?

Comment: I have sdk version 28 also, ads not showing i have tried normal banner and smart banner also same problem ...

Comment: @Dreamer can you show ads in android 9, in now? i have same problem with you. my ads can show in old android ( i test in android below 9) but can not show in android 9

Comment: Same problem with Samsung devices android 9 not showing ads

Comment: Hi @KennethLi, please help us

Comment: I gave you best answer but my real problem was in target country .. Low match rate